# Issues pulling data from server

Tags: sql, psql, qliksense

I'm attempting to pull data from an Oracle Database where the timestamp is in UTC time, but I'm attempting to pull using CST, based on the information that a client has requested.

Basically, I'm looking to pull the information based on the code for the previous day, but I also need to account for the time difference to Central time(-6 hours), so essentially, I need to pull information for the previous 30 or so hours.

Here is my below code:

```
SELECT *
FROM SPROBSUMMARYM1 PM1 
JOIN SPROBSUMMARYM2 PM2 ON PM1."NUMBER" = PM2."NUMBER"
JOIN SCOMPUTERM1 Com1 ON PM1."FS_MACHINE" = Com1."MACHINE_NAME"
where PM1."OPEN_TIME" > TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 AND PM1."OPEN_TIME"<TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Comment: Are you using Postgresql or Oracle?

Comment: I'm actually using a combination of both, as I'm pulling data through ODBC and from a SQL server.

I'm using a web based application called Qliksense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle time, 1 is a full day, one hour is 1/24. To get 6 hours you would use 6/24. SO your SQL should become

```
SELECT *
  FROM sprobsummarym1 pm1
       JOIN sprobsummarym2 pm2 ON pm1."NUMBER" = pm2."NUMBER"
       JOIN scomputerm1 com1 ON pm1."FS_MACHINE" = com1."MACHINE_NAME"
 WHERE pm1."OPEN_TIME" > TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 1 - 6/24
   AND pm1."OPEN_TIME" < TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 6/24;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Brian. Looks like that solved my issue I was having!